# Updating Nested Object in React State

Tags: reactjs, nested, state

I have a state with nested object in it. I need to `setState()` the state value with the `onChange` event with every word I write in the input section.

i tried to update directly with `this.state.rootProperty.childProperty` but it creates a new state `rootProperty.childProperty: "value i wrote"`.

Any ideas on how to `setState` those nested state?
Thanks.

```
    this.state = {
      taskData: "",
      memberData: "",
      judul: "",
      kode: "",
      ketua_team: "",
      koordinator: "",
      tgl_mulai: "",
      tgl_selesai: "",
      detail1: {
        no: "",
        tiket: "",
        deskripsi: "",
        target: "",
        auditor: "",
        nil_peg: "",
        nil_at: "",
        nil_at_at: "",
      },

//this is my state, i need to update auditor value with handler

onChangeNest(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

//and my input props
 <input
 type="text"
 placeholder="auditor"
 name="detail1.auditor"
 onChange={this.onChangeNest}
 ></input>
```

Comment: please provide a code snippet

Comment: also, you never set state directly. you must always use `setState`

Comment: @Apostolos, yes i use setState.

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: @Apostolos your answer works like a charm, thanks a lot man.

Comment: tgl_selesai: this.state.tgl_selesai,
      detail1: {
        no: this.state.detail1.no,
        tiket: this.state.detail1.tiket,

is this a correct code if i want to POST my current state to mongoDB?

i logged it but the auditor value didn't send, all the detail1 value actually was didn't send as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only for 1 level nested object, you could try the following:

```
  onChangeNest = (e) => {
    let targetName = e.target.name
    if (targetName.includes(".")) {
      let splt = targetName.split(".")
      let oldObj = {...this.state[splt[0]]}
      oldObj[splt[1]] = e.target.value
      this.setState({ [splt[0]]: oldObj })
    } else {
      this.setState({ [targetName]: e.target.value })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

setState doesn't handle updates on nested properties. One of the possible solutions is to copy the entire state (create a dummy object), modify it and update state with the fully modified object.

It's really well explained in this answer. You might find it helpful:

[How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)